# .htaccess - Redirect from server root to index.php on a specific folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to configure my virtual server, but I have some problem with the .htaccess url rewrite options.

my server has this structure:

- webdomain

  - sitefolder

    - otherfolder

      - public

        - index.php

I want that any kind of request are redirect to index.php and I want that the users when go to www.webdomain.com they are redirect to www.webdomain.com/public.

This is my try located in webdomain folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ sitefolder/otherfolder/public/index.php [NC,L]
```

With this I'm albe only to redirect to index.php only when I navigate up to public folder.

Comment: "I'm albe only to redirect to index.php only when I navigate up to public folder." - what do you mean by this? If you explicitly navigate to the `public` folder then no redirect needs to occur anyway? Is `webdomain` your _document root_?

Comment: I'm using zend framework, so in public folder there is index.php (that should manage all request) and there are css, js and images file. the core of the application is under "otherfolder". webdomain is my html folder (standard apache installation)

Comment: @w3dk do you have any idea how to do it?